Standards/Insight into Transient Protection of Industrial/Construction Equipment
I am designing a device that will be connected to the 12 or 24V battery of certain construction and industrial equipment.  I'm aware that because these are industrial vehicles/equipment we will need to design to protect from transients up to hundreds of volts, however I don't have much more insight than that.
If there are any ISO or other standards I can use as a guideline that would help (such as ISO 7637-2 for road vehicles), or if anyone has personal experience of worst-case transients seen on this type of equipment, it would help a lot!
Thank you
